# Will Microsoft make exceptions on their BizSpark entry requirements

Tags: requirements, bizspark

The company I work for is about three and a half years old but we haven't started developing software until recently. Is the less than three years old rule absolute or will they make exceptions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only Microsoft can answer it. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: @Kara Fair enough, it's a 6 year old question anyway!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: @EJoshuaS No worries, this was asked about three years before that meta post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't realy know if that's the reason you are interested in bizspark but if you sign up for the free software through this:

http://www.asp.net/downloads

and then follow the links on the e-mails, you can get legitimate copies/keys of the software!